# Text parsing a file path in batch script

Tags: parsing, batch-file, filenames, batch-processing, filepath

I'd like to set a file's name to a variable in a batch file. I'm already pulling the file name by pulling the total path length. Is there a way I can parse the path to only give me back the file name?

The particular script that I use to pull the path looks like this:

```
for /f "delims=_" %%J IN ('forfiles /p "%%F" /m *.extension /c "cmd /c echo @path"')  
DO start "Program"  /D "c:\fullpath" /Wait program -r  %%J
```

Also, if there's an easier way to pull the file name and put it into a variable I'm open to that as well.

Comment: where the `"%%F"` comes from? is this nested for loop?

Comment: Honestly I don't know, this is a loop a coworker sent me that he uses to pull files with.

Comment: So you just want the file name passed to the `"program"` ?

Comment: the program is running the files. The loop is from a script that is used to automatically run all the files in a particular folder. The `%%J` is the full path for each file.

Comment: to get file name use `%%~nxJ` or `%%~nJ` to strip the extension.

Comment: I'm still learning batch scripting. Could you explain how that works to strip the path and extension?

Comment: @David: it's explained in `for /?`